# SPRING form:option "Unterminated &lt;form:option tag"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

I'm newbie about Spring

I cannot solve this problem although I try `</form:option>` or `<form:option ..../>`

**JSP**

```
<form:select path="status" 
    id="cbo-position-status" class="editable-select">
        <c:forEach items="${statusMap}" var = "stt">
            <form:option  value="<c:out value="${stt.id}"/>" label="<c:out value="${stt.name}"/>"/>

        </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

**Controller**

```
List<StatusBean> statuses = commonService.getAllStatus(6);
Map<Integer, String> status = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
status.put(statuses.get(0).getId(), statuses.get(0).getName());
model.addAttribute("statusMap", status);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using double quotes within double quotes :) Use single quotation within double quotations if they are nested.

Change the  as follows:

```
<form:option  value="<c:out value='${stt.id}'/>" label="<c:out value='${stt.name}'/>"/>
```

Let me know if this resolves.

Comment: This should have been selected as answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can direct map like below.

1. jsp page

   ```
   <form:options items="${user}" itemLabel="tbuser_username" itemValue="tbuser_id"/>
   ```
2. controller

   ```
   model.addObject("user", projectservice.getUsers());
   ```

I hope you are understand and improve your code.

Comment: Hi, the return type of  my variable model is just Model , not ModelAndView so model.addAttribute is  OK ???? @sanjay

Answer (score 0):

Remove your

```
<c:out value='${stt.id}'/>
```

by

```
<form:option>
```

and try example below:

```
    <c:forEach items="${statusMap}" var = "stt">
        <core:set var="actionValueId" value="${stt.id}"/>
        <core:set var="actionValueName" value="${stt.name}"/>
        <form:option  value="${actionValueId}" label="${actionValueName}"/>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use JSP Tags inside the attributes of other JSP Tags. You can use the `var` attribute instead.

```
<c:out value="${stt.id}" var="id"/>
<c:out value="${stt.name}" var="name"/>
<form:option  value="${id}" label="${name}"/>
```